# Rails validations with parameters

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation

In my code below, I am trying to call `url_exist?` as a validation for the website, but I am unsure of how to call `url_exist?` with the value of website. This seems like a silly question, but I can not figure it out.

**Model**

```
validates :website, presence: true, if: :url_exist?
...
def url_exist?(url_string)
  url = URI.parse(url_string)
  puts url
  binding.pry
  req.use_ssl = (url.scheme == 'https')
  req = Net::HTTP.new(url.host, url.port)
  path = url.path if url.path.present?
  req.request_head(path || '/')
  res.code != "404" # false if returns 404 - not found
rescue Errno::ENOENT
  false # false if can't find the server
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You already know the value of `website` because it's one of the object's attributes. So, just reference it in your `url_exist?` function.

```
validates :website, presence: true, if: :url_exist?

# ...

def url_exist?
  url = URI.parse(self.website)
  puts url
  # ...
end
```

I should also note that it seems like you're missing some code towards the end of the snippet you posted, so right now your `url_exist?` function will always return false.